# Print iFrame content using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

I want to print iFrame content using javascript. I've tried to following but it only works in Chrome.

```
window.frames[frameid].print();
```

and

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframeID").contentWindow;
iframe.focus();
iframe.print();
```

It is not working on Mozilla Firefox.

I'm showing PDF in iFrame on a page.

Comment: This won't work if iframe is on different domain than the window from which you're executing this code.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'm loading the PDF from the same domain.

Comment: @Teemu corrected the typo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.contentWindow.print();` worked for me.

I've opened the PDF in iframe of fancybox and then called `.contentWindow.print();`.

> Though it's not supported in some older browsers.

Comment: It does not work in Firefox without setting cross domain origin to source period, not only older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `onload="window.print();"` in the `body` tag of the iframe code.

Or you could simply use:

```
<script>window.print();</script>
```

Anywhere in the source code of the `iframe`.

It also appears you've made a typo. Replace `ifrmae` with `iframe`.

Comment: As I've mentioned I'm loading PDF file directly in the iframe, so I don't know where I can add window.print() function.