# Print the iframe content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to print the content of the iframe. I viewd several examples but non of them helped me for my case. I have the following piece of code

```
<div id="print-area">
    <iframe src='data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<?php echo $content ?>'></iframe>
</div>
```

And when the #print button is clicked: (this code prints out the content of the div #print-area)

```
$("#print").click(function (e) {
        var newWindow = window.open();
        newWindow.document.write($('#print-area').html());
        newWindow.print()
    });
```

The code works and print window is prompted, but when I try to put content of the iframe in the document.write(...) the function does not work. Any idea?

tried solutions:

[Print iFrame content using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716862/print-iframe-content-using-javascript)

[How to Print iframe content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697308/how-to-print-iframe-content)

and from other topics, but did not manage to print my iframe content

Answer (score 1):

use

```
<iframe id="abcd" src='data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<?php echo "someHtmlContent" ?>'>


            </iframe>
var newWindow = window.open();
                newWindow.document.write($('#abcd').contents().find("html").html());
                newWindow.print()
```

because iframe is a independent page it not access by windows class 
that why use parent class

Comment: I cant do it... May be not sure how exactly. Can you give me example

Comment: if you have any demo link then share with me i will solve your problem.